# Ubuntu unity 14.04 built-in display can't be turned off

Tags: unity, 14.04, display-resolution

My resolution is messed up, but the built-in display cannot be turned off and I cannot adjust it, in fact not even get to see all settings below. I checked if my SIS video card driver is properly installed, but that seems to be the case. There is no problem with a second monitor or anything, which seems to be a known bug. I have browsed the forum, but I cannot find how I can fix it. Do I maybe need to create a xorg.conf file?